# Error/difference of sampling an element from a set

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, variance, means

Assume there is a set, $A_j={x_1, x_2,...,x_n}$. What should be the error associated in selecting/choosing an element from $A_j$, given each element of $A_j$ has an equal probability ($1/n$) of getting selected?

Would average provide a good estimate?

e.g.,
$Error=|x'-(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)/n|$

The ultimate goal is to estimate the sample statistics (mean, variance) where, the sample is composed of $x'_1,x'_2,...,x'_k$ where $x'_i$ is drawn from $k$ number of sets $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$.

Comment: Somewhat tautologically, if you are interested with deviation from the mean, then the deviation from the mean is a good estimate of that error. But as long as you don't specify what you mean by "the error" this question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I edited the question so that it gives more clarity on what I'm looking for. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [link](https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/mae-and-rmse-which-metric-is-better-e60ac3bde13d). You may report both RMSE and MAE.